# Boost Regex Exclude one character

Tags: c++, regex, boost, regex-negation

I'm locking for a boost regular expression that would exclude all strings that contains the character **|**.

- "1234|" should be exclude
- "|eee" should be exclude
- "...ff" should not be exclude.

I can't change the code above to remove the negation of the result of boost::regex_match.

```
if ( !boost::regex_match( sValue, boost::regex("[^\|]") ) )
{
// string contains character |
}
else
{
// string doesn't contains character |
}
```

Why the regular expression [^\|] doesn't meet my needs ?

Comment: Not an answer, but you can't do it without a regex as well: `sValue.find('|') == std::string::npos`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code above is part of a framework and I need to use a regex expression and I can't modify the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found finally the right regex: `^[^|]*$`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do would to exclude when regex `"\|"` *does* match. (It's also more efficient).

Also, you clearly don't need regex for this:

```
bool exclude = (std::string::npos != s.find('|'));
```